# Tracking Member, Non-Members using GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

i need too track Members and non-members in the website using google tag manager. specifically, it is important to distinguish users prior and after sign up process and not overwrite them as members (even though they entered the website and non-members). i don't want to push the data directly to the google analytic so i need to create tags in google tag manager to be fired.

any suggestion?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Custom Dimensions to track the status of visitors on your site. For more information on Dimensions, you may find more details on Google's Support pages: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033861

This would allow you to segment the data and Reports in Analytics based on those Dimensions.

Otherwise, if you cannot send data to Google Analytics from Tag Manager, you might want to track users by settings cookies according the specific Rules. This article provides a gist of how to set cookies from within Tag Manager: http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/universal-analytics-fire-script-just-per-session/